# How to better style a checkbox? Toggleclass isn't working and it seems to require an id - how can I make this checkmark icon invisible before checking

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to style a checkbox and have achieved a method of changing the background color - see below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<style>
body,
html {
  font-family: "Lato", monospace;
  font-size: calc(1rem + 1vw);
}
.label__checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.label__checkbox i.icon {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: calc(9rem + 1vw);
  color: transparent;
}
.label__check {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.label__check i.icon {
  opacity: 0.2;
  font-size: calc(9rem + 1vw);
  color: white;
}
.label__check:hover {
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.label__checkbox:checked + .label__text .label__check {
  -webkit-animation: check 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22) forwards;
          animation: check 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22) forwards;
}
.label__checkbox:checked + .label__text .label__check .icon {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0);
  color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
@-webkit-keyframes check {
  100% {
    width: 10em;
    height: 2em;
    background: #00d478;
    border: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes check {
  100% {
    width: 10em;
    height: 2em;
    background: #00d478;
    border: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.normal {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: blueviolet;
}
.bigger {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: forestgreen;
}

</style>



<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <div class="center"> <label class="label">
         <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" />
         <span class="label__text">
           <span class="label__check">
             <i class="fa fa-check icon"></i>
           </span>
         </span>   </label>

</body>

</html>
```

My issue is that the checkmark icon shows when the box is unchecked.  This causes some confusion for some (apparently).  I've been trying to use toggleclass with jquery to replace the image with something else, but I can't get that working.  I've also just tried to make the initial checkmark not visible, but for some reason my attempts to make the visibility hidden are not working.  Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Instead of a fiddle, you should make the code you posted into a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: an empty jsfiddle is not helpfull. did you copy/pate tha html/css and noticed that it was CSS written for LESS and it needed to be compiled ?

Comment: @Tom — it means it's runnable right here, I don't have to leave your question to work with your code; it means it won't disappear sometime in the future, as fiddles have sometimes done, making the question less helpful to future readers; and there's a "copy code to answer" feature. It also means more people will be willing to attempt working with your code and thus answering your question.

Comment: Ok, got rid of the fiddle - anyone have any idea of how to get this little checkmark to disappear or be replaceable with a different icon class?  Thanks again.